# iOS swift parse update multiple objects

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

i have 2 objects(parent , child)  with cash and value fields for each object .
at pressing a button , it does some calculations and update objects fields to the new values ,I'm able to update the parent fields to the new values but the child values remain as they are.

heres the full code :

```
@IBOutlet weak var childImage: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var childInfo: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var adoptButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var nextButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var malesButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var femalesButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var statusLabel: UILabel!

// empty array to load ids from parse
var objectIds = [String]()

// counter is the index number of Ids array
var counter = 0

var childCash = 0
var childValue = 0
var childId: String? = ""
var childName = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    loadingMalesIds()
    childInfo.hidden = true
    adoptButton.hidden = true
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



@IBAction func maleButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

   loadingMalesIds()
}

@IBAction func femaleButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    loadingFemalesIds()

}

 @IBAction func nextButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {




    counter++

        if (counter <= objectIds.count){
        var query = PFQuery(className:"_User")
        query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(objectIds[(counter - 1) ] ) {
            (child: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil && child != nil {
                 self.childName = child?["username"] as! String
                self.childValue = child?["value"] as! Int
                var status = child?["status"] as! String
                self.childCash = child?["cash"] as! Int
                self.childId =  (child?.objectId)!


                let userImageFile = child?["userImage"] as! PFFile
                userImageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
                    (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                    if error == nil {
                        if let imageData = imageData {
                            let image = UIImage(data:imageData)
                            self.childImage.layer.borderWidth = 2
                            self.childImage.layer.masksToBounds = true
                            self.childImage.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
                            self.childImage.image = image
                        }
                    }
                }

                self.statusLabel.text = status
                self.childInfo.text = "\(self.childName), $\(self.childValue)"
             } else {
                println(error)
            } // end of if error == nil
        }

        }else{
            counter = 0
    } //end of if (counter <= objectIds.count)







    childInfo.hidden = false
    adoptButton.hidden = false

}//end of method

 func loadingMalesIds(){
    objectIds.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

    var query = PFQuery(className:"_User")

    // get Ids with a condition that users are males
    query.whereKey("gender", equalTo:"male")

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            // The find succeeded.
             if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                for object in objects {
                    self.objectIds.append((object.objectId)! as String)


                }
            }
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            println("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")
        }
    }
    self.malesButton.enabled = false
    self.femalesButton.enabled = true




}
func loadingFemalesIds(){
    objectIds.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

    var query = PFQuery(className:"_User")

    // get Ids with a condition that users are males
    query.whereKey("gender", equalTo:"female")

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            // The find succeeded.
            if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                for object in objects {
                    self.objectIds.append((object.objectId)! as String)

                }
            }
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            println("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")
        }
    }
    self.malesButton.enabled = true
    self.femalesButton.enabled = false




}

 @IBAction func adoptPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    // get parent cash and value
    let cash = PFUser.currentUser()!["cash"] as? Int
    let value = PFUser.currentUser()!["value"] as? Int
    let numberOfChildren = PFUser.currentUser()!["numberOfChildren"] as? Int



    //check
    if (cash < childValue){
        noCashAlert()
    }else{

        var parentNewCash = cash! - childValue
        var parentNewValue = value! + childValue

        var childNewCash = childCash + (10 * childValue / 100)

        //number of children 
        var newNumberOfChildren = numberOfChildren! + 1

        // save parent new cash and value
        var queryParent = PFQuery(className:"_User")

        //get parent ID
        var currentUserId = PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId!
        println("current: \(currentUserId)")

        // do the saving operation
        queryParent.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(currentUserId!) {
            (parent: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                println(error)
            } else if let parent = parent {

                //parent new cash
                parent["cash"] = parentNewCash
                //parent new value
                parent["value"] = parentNewValue
               //parent number of children

                parent["numberOfChildren"] = newNumberOfChildren

                 parent.saveInBackground()
             }
        }//end parent query


            var queryChild = PFQuery(className:"_User")


            queryChild.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(self.childId!) {
                (child: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if error != nil {
                    println(error)
                } else if let child = child {
                    child["cash"] = childNewCash

                    child.saveInBackground()
                }
            }//end child query




         }





}

func noCashAlert(){
    let message = "Sorry!, You Don't Have Enough Money,You Can Use Money Printer For Some Extra Cash "
    let okText = "Ok"
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    let okayButton = UIAlertAction(title: okText, style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil)
    alert.addAction(okayButton)
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

We need more information.

One possibility is that `childValue` is declared as an `Int`, and its value is less than 100, so that `childValue / 100` is 0. Remember integer division vs. floating-point division. You could say instead `Double(childValue) / 100.0` to force floating point.

Have you used a debugger or debugging `println()`s to determine if `childNewCash` is what you expect?

Another possibility is that child is declared as a struct not a class, but this is very unlikely given the context.

As a minor style point, you probably want:

```
if let e = error {
   println(e)
}
```

so that you don't get `Optional(...)` in your output.

This answer should have gone into comments section but for now I'll keep it and just edit...This is impossible to answer without a lot more context. When you say "it's not updating at all" where and when are you looking?

If you're looking in the `getObjectInBackgroundWithId` completion handler right after setting the cash value, I'm sure you'd get the right value back.

Are you looking in the cloud database? With a background save there's some delay, and you could be looking too early. If there's conflicting saves, the save tasks could be overwriting one another. How about using the optional completion handler for `saveInBackground()` to make sure you're not checking too soon?

Comment: yea i used println..here an example I'm testing on but won't update..childCash = 5000...childValue = 500..output : childNewCash: 5050 @BazeZen

Comment: i set childNewCash = 1000 and tried to update , its not updating at all , i don't think the problem with the calculation more than implementing the right method . i don't know why its updating for parents and not for child although its the same method , what do you think about retrieving the object id? @BaseZen

Comment: i have been looking for an answer for 2 days without any results :/ , thats the whole class ..pleaseee help @BaseZen

Comment: I think this is a system problem, not a Swift problem. The interaction with a cloud database is a big unknown. I think you'd have to post a .zip to the entire project and ensure the environment you have is completely reproducible -- which iOS device and/or simulator, which version of Xcode, and all related 'parse.com' credentials. If that's at all feasible I could take a look out of curiosity but it's sort of out of the bounds of the SOF Q/A format.

Comment: thats very strange , this is one of the very basic operation and it's not working , very disappointing

Comment: By system problem, I still mean it's your error, unless you're disappointed in yourself :-D But seriously, all I'm trying to say is there's still not enough info here. There are many points of failure in a multi-tiered App.

Comment: hehe..i just knew the reason , parse simply doesn't allow manipulating other users data , updating fields only apply on current user , there is no way of updating other users fields, thanks for your help brother i appreciate  @BaseZen

Comment: solution was creating a custom class not a User class @BaseZen